# StaticMaps working when using wifi, but not working when using cellular data

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, google-maps

I build website to get location(geolocation).

It works fine when I'm using wifi data, but its not working properly when Im using cellular data. It gives me blank image.

Any suggestion?

Here is my code:

```
function jsfGetLocation()
{
    if      ( navigator.geolocation ) { navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(jsfShowPosition,jsfShowError); }
        else    { document.getElementById("DivMap").innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser."; };
};

function jsfShowPosition(position)
{
    var MapWidth = document.getElementById("Div").offsetWidth - 2;
    var LttLng = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
    var StrImgURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=[MyKey]&center=" + LttLng + "&zoom=14&size=" + MapWidth + "x300&sensor=true&markers=color:red%7C" + LttLng;
    document.getElementById("Div").innerHTML = "<img src='" + StrImgURL + "'>";

    document.getElementById("ToolBarLt").textContent = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById("ToolBarLn").textContent = position.coords.longitude;
};
```

But I don't think that its about script error. I think its because of privilege data use on chrome or the iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check on this [forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7107038?start=0&tstart=0). This might be also because of issues with the services. This happens usually on older iPhones who have upgraded from iOS 8 to iOS 9. You can also read this [thread](http://osxdaily.com/2015/09/24/ios-9-cellular-data-not-working-troubleshooting/) with some troubleshooting tips about this issue. You can update iOS to the newest version and/or [resetting the device network settings](http://osxdaily.com/2010/01/11/fix-iphone-cellular-data-problems-by-resetting-network-settings/) and then reboot the device. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

maybe u should change another device, try. So that we can find out what is the problem

Comment: its fine if im using android.

Comment: change another iphone to try.

Comment: give me the link.. i can try this